# How it is possible to insert an int when the column serializer is String?

Tags: cassandra, astyanax

From the [Getting Started](https://github.com/Netflix/astyanax/wiki/Getting-Started) page of Astyanax:

```
ColumnFamily<String, String> CF_USER_INFO =
 new ColumnFamily<String, String>(
     "Standard1",              // Column Family Name
     StringSerializer.get(),   // Key Serializer
     StringSerializer.get());  // Column Serializer
```

So the key is a String and the column value is a String also. But later:

```
m.withRow(CF_USER_INFO, "acct1234")
.putColumn("firstname", "john", null)
.putColumn("lastname", "smith", null)
.putColumn("address", "555 Elm St", null)
.putColumn("age", 30, null);
```

The last putColumn statement uses "30" (int value) as the value for the column.
How this is possible since the earlier declaration puts that the column value is a String?

Answer (score 1):

You can set the serializer for each individual column. Here is one way of doing it with Hector (the following code is JRuby so not a lot of type declarations):

```
cluster = HFactory.getOrCreateCluster("my_cluster","localhost:9160")
keyspace = HFactory.createKeyspace("my_keyspace", cluster)
ss = StringSerializer.new
is = IntegerSerializer.new
mut = HFactory.createMutator(keyspace, ss)
mut.addInsertion("my_key", "my_column_family", HFactory.createColumn("age",50,ssis))
mut.execute()
```

Comment: I'm interested in Astyanax example. They didn't set/override the serializer for putColumn("age", 30, null)

Answer (score 1):

if someone need this

```
            ksDef = cluster.makeKeyspaceDefinition();

            ksDef.setName(keyspaceName)
                    .setStrategyOptions(keyspaceOptions)
                    .setStrategyClass("SimpleStrategy")
                        .addColumnFamily(
                                cluster.makeColumnFamilyDefinition()
                                        .setName("yourcf")
                                        .setDefaultValidationClass("UTF8Type")
                                        .setKeyValidationClass("UTF8Type")
                                        .addColumnDefinition(
                                        cluster.makeColumnDefinition()
                                                setName("flag")
                                                .setValidationClass("BooleanType"));
```

I'm using [ThrifeKeyspaceImplTest.java](https://github.com/Netflix/astyanax/blob/master/src/test/java/com/netflix/astyanax/thrift/ThrifeKeyspaceImplTest.java) unit test for reference, there are plenty of examples.

Answer (score 0):

Two reasons that this is possible:

First, the astyanax example does not set a validation class for the column value (validator).

Second, Astyanax provides strongly typed putColumn methods for most primitive types (and a few others - e.g. ByteBuffer, UUID, etc) and the putColumn implementation handles the serialization on your behalf.

```java
@Override 
public ColumnListMutation<C> putColumn(C columnName, int value, Integer ttl) {
    return putColumn(columnName, value, IntegerSerializer.get(), ttl);
}
```

See [/astyanax-cassandra/src/main/java/com/netflix/astyanax/AbstractColumnListMutation.java#L159](https://github.com/Netflix/astyanax/blob/master/astyanax-cassandra/src/main/java/com/netflix/astyanax/AbstractColumnListMutation.java#L159)

Regarding validators, you can setValidationClass on a ColumnDefinition programmatically in astyanax (and hector) or via setting column_metadata thru the CLI.  See: http://www.datastax.com/docs/0.8/configuration/storage_configuration#column-metadata